# How do i display the same recurring product in a table? I.e. Same product (macbook) that has been serviced at different locations

Tags: sql, mysqli, product

I am fairly new to SQL queries. I want to display the same product that has been serviced at three different labs or service stations.

I want to list and display the macbook represented by the id at the three different stations (or more) being displayed too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so normally on stackoverflow, people tend to show what they tried and why it didn't work. In fact this question will probably be closed as too broad, but I empathize with starting with sql. But I will match the broadness of your question with a broad answer.

You should splt the tables up. I might try to have three tables:

1. A table describing each product with unique id
2. A table describing each service location with a unique id
3. A table describing each transaction with a unique id consisting of product ID and location id

Then when you need the data you would perform a join which would return the table containing the information you want.